# How to create a delayed startup command

Tags: nvidia, screen, tearing, nvidia-settings, redshift

this question might be simple but I'm new to Linux..
i had a screen tear issue with my nvidia graphics card, i looked up a YT vid and it said it has something to do with the composition pipeline and  explained how to fix it by adding the command line below to the nvidia configuration file..
It worked, the screen tear is gone, but it created another problem. a program called "redshift" wouldn't work anymore..
anyhow, i rolled back the changes that vid said and spent the night trying to get to the bottom of it, and i found a solution.

all i need to do is i just boot my pc and after redshift starts, i run this command in terminal:

"nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="HDMI-0:1280x720_60 +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"

Template:
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="CONNECTION:RESOLUTION_RATE +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"

somehow, redshift is not affected by it because it already started, and at the same time, the screen tear problem is solved ( until i restart the computer), then i have to execute the command again..

I'm now looking for an automated solution ,maybe by creating a delayed script with this command in "session and startup" that will execute after "Redshift" starts.

How do i do that? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Startup Applications to delay the start of Dropbox until after my VPN has loaded.  The same procedure might work for your case.  I would try the following:

Open Startup Applications (click on the dash and search for it)

Add a new startup program by clicking the Add button and give it a name.

In the command line try:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep XX && YOUR NVIDIA code"
```

where XX is the number of seconds of delay you want before executing. So,

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="HDMI-0:1280x720_60 +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }
```

then click Save and reboot to verify that it works.