# How can I automatically turn off an external monitor that has been idle for a certain amount of time using a command/script?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, bash, scripts, external-monitor

Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
Desktop with Nvidia dedicated Card GPU.

When I set power saving to blank screen on an external monitor to turn off the monitor for power saving, it gets reset to default 100% brightness once power saving is active.

I'm not familiar with Bash, but I wondered if I could write a Bash script to automatically turn off the monitor without going to active blank screen?

I have installed `xprintidle` to detect the idle time.

Here is how I wanted it to run:

If idle time is over 600 seconds (10 minutes) then run this power off monitor command `xset dpms force off`

I want it to load on startup and keep on running like a service which will turn off the monitor if idle for 10 minutes.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with xprintidle. All you need to do is configure a periodic check inside an infinite loop. If the system is idle, you turn the display off.

I created a service that can do this for the purpose of powering down machines after a period of inactivity, but it can be used to run any shell command after a period of inactivity. You can find the script with documentation on [my GitHub page](https://github.com/nbros652/bash-idle-action).

I am currently using this to do exactly what you describe on a laptop with an NVIDIA card. I have mine set to time out at 300 seconds (5 minutes) with a check every 10 seconds, so it could potentially remain idle for about 310 seconds before blanking the screen, but the variance of 10 seconds doesn't matter to me.

Comment: I am on a desktop with dedicated nvidia GPU running 440 driver.Can you explain more on how i edit your script to turn off the monitor ? I tried adding a command xset dpms 10 20 30 on .profile but it does not work on startup . https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023796/how-to-create-a-delayed-startup-command

Comment: Did you install the service using the `systemctl enable ...` command as specified on my GitHub page? You need to download both of the files from my GitHub page and drop them in the locations specified. Then you need to edit the script file (filename ending in .sh) and change the `idleCmd` variable to `xset dpms force off`. You can edit the script file with any file editor. I use nano. Just make sure to edit with sudo.

Comment: Do i need to create a new directory on `/root/scripts` ?
I place the .sh into `/usr/local/bin/on-idle-service.sh ? Active Failed at ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/on-idle-service.sh (code=exited, status Main PID: 1122 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)` I had change the `idleCmd="xset dpms force off"` . `Chmod 770 the .sh` , `sudo systemctl enable on-idle` , `sudo systemctl start on-idle` What did I miss ?

Comment: The line 22 `on-idle-service.sh[1136]: /root/scripts/on-idle-service.sh: line 22: / 1000 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ 1000 ")` `idleTime=$[ $userIdle / 1000 ] ` shows up an error. @b_laoshi

Comment: The path to the script doesn't really matter so long as you update the service file and mark the script itself as executable. From the error you're getting on line 22, it sounds like either the XAUTHORITY or DISPLAY environment variables are not being set correctly. You may have to determine what the values of these should be by running `printenv` while locally logged into a desktop session. Then manually set them in the script.

Comment: At printenv `XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority` and `DISPLAY=:0` https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bSrj62f7Hr/ .Which line and what i should set at the script ? b_laoshi

Comment: How should I determine the value ?

Comment: I copy the same code without changing but it still does not run. @ b_laoshi have not been online for a week. Any other user can reply @WinEunuuchs2Unix